# Load data using Node.js and PostGis

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I have a huge file of data points, and I would like to load them. I am using Leaflet(Front-End)/Node.Js(Back-end)

I wanted to load the data that is inside borders.
I have two choices:

- Using Node.Js
- Using Leaflet (this is bad idea, 'cause the file is two huge to be
  processed)

Now I want to load data whenever I move browser, The confusing part to me is, how can I load file every time from every move in front end

Move/Zoom Page (front End) ----> get Bounds --> On Node.JS Side (Back-end) --> Load data from PostGis by querying it using ORM --> write it on geojson file ---> plot data using on front-end part

main.js

1- Detect Movement / Zoom on 
    ... 
    map.on('dragend', getPins);
    map.on('zoomend', getPins);
    ...

```
function getPins(e){
    bounds = map.getBounds();
    var latMax = map.getBounds().getNorthEast().lat();
    var lngMax = map.getBounds().getNorthEast().lng();
    var latMin = map.getBounds().getSouthWest().lat();
    var lngMin = map.getBounds().getSouthWest().lng();
    var centerLATT = map.getCenter().lat();
    var centerLON = map.getCenter().lng();
    var centerZOOM = map.getZoom();
}
```

Node.Js / Express

```
var express = require('express');
var app = new express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
var port = Number(process.env.PORT || 5000);
app.listen(port);
```

2- Node module for returning PostGIS queries  from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12766289/format-geojson-from-postgis)

I would like to update the point by loading from Postgis

```
var postgeo = require("postgeo");

postgeo.connect("postgres://user@host:port/database");

postgeo.query(
    'SELECT gid,name,ST_X(the_geom) as longitude,ST_Y(the_geom) as latitude FROM  GeoDataTable WHERE ST_Intersects( ST_MakeEnvelope('+latMax+", "+lngMax+", "+latMin+", "+lngMin" ', function(data) {

    for(i=0; i<data.rows.length; i++){
        var feature = new Feature();
        feature.geometry = JSON.parse(result.rows[i].locale);
        feature.properties = {"TTL", result.rows[i].ttl};
        featureCollection.features.push(feature);
    }
});
```

The problem is how can I pass latMax,lngMax,latMin,lngMin from front-end to backend and pass json file loaded from data base from back-end to front end automatically.

Comment: This is such a convoluted problem. What's the question. how do you load data into postgres? how do you get data from leaflet? or how does a webserver work?

Answer (score -2):

You can use [socket.io](http://socket.io/) to communicate with the node.js server in real time with the browser.

Your question is very generic, so it would take a lot of coding here to solve your problem, but basically you can use the `socket.emit` function from the socket.io library to send data from the browser to the server, and server back to the browser.